# How can I pass a pre-generated secret key to a user's device securely, without creating a server?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, certificate

It can be a one time thing, as the passed key can then be stored on the users device via android keystore.

What I'm ideally wanting, is a secure place to store a secret key, that is accessible by my app, which on installing the app, can retrieve and store this key locally.

My immediate thought is using certificates but I don't know too much about them, nor any service that can help me.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you expect to send any data what-so-ever to a device without another device which is typically called a server?

Comment: I was wondering if there was some kind of online service that stores information like this, and the app would then request it as needed. Or perhaps android itself offers a solution to developers?

Comment: I don't feel like there is enough information to answer the question well.  For example, what stops someone else from downloading and publishing (stealing) the key?  If the key is accessible via download by your app then it is effectively public.  If the key is random per installation then why not generate a new key and upload it to the server instead?  Knowing what you actually want to accomplish might help.

Comment: The app encrypts and decrypts messages using the same symmetric key. I need this key to be the same on every installation of this app so that they can decrypt each others messages. However I don't want the key to be hardcoded into the app. I need a way of accessing this key from multiple devices

Comment: @numberjak If any user of your app simply reverse engineers your app, they can make the exact same request to download the key. If you can't prevent that then you might as well hard code the key in the code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cryptography engineering and not really programming.  I suggest you check out crypto.stackexchange.com and gain some grounding in theory.